# use a specific profile to create ecr repository with AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I am new in AWS CLI. I have configured my aws & in my `~/.aws/config` I have two profiles:

```
[profile dev]
...

[profile prod]
...
```

Now, I would like to create an ECR registry from command line with my `dev` profile (which is associated with our development environment in AWS cloud).

I checked [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/create-repository.html) document, and I get that I could execute a command like:

```
aws ecr create-repository \
    --repository-name sample-repo \
    --image-tag-mutability IMMUTABLE
```

But how can I specify the `dev` profile to use when executing this command?

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html#using-profiles) is how you can use the named profile.

```
aws ecr create-repository \
    --repository-name sample-repo \
    --image-tag-mutability IMMUTABLE \
    --profile dev
```